# Listing all tags for an acts_as_taggable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I have an app that has factoids that have tags using the acts_as_taggable gem. I currently have it setup so that when on the index page for the factoids, clicking on any of the tags filters the factoids by that tag. What I am attempting to do now is create an index page that lists all of the tags in the app. This seemed rather straight forward...

1. create a `tag.rb`
2. create a `tags_controller.rb`
3. add a view in `tags/index.html.erb`

The problem is that this causes my previously implemented search to break. If there are any additional things that are needed, please let me know.

**FactoidsController (the index part of it)**

```
class FactoidsController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  # GET /factoids
  # GET /factoids.json
  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @factoids = Factoid.tagged_with(params[:tag]).order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => params[:page])
    else
      @factoids = Factoid.search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => params[:page])
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @factoids }
    end
  end

  def tagged
    if params[:tag].present?
      @factoids = Factoid.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @factoids = Factoid.postall
    end
  end

  private
  def sort_column
    params[:sort] || "created_at"
  end

  def sort_direction
    params[:direction] || "desc"
  end

end
```

**Tags Controller**

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  # GET /factoids
  # GET /factoids.json
  def index
    @tags = Tag.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @tags }
    end
  end

  private
  def sort_column
    params[:sort] || "created_at"
  end

  def sort_direction
    params[:direction] || "desc"
  end

end
```

**Routes**

```
QaApp::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  resources :factoids

  resources :tags

  get "home/index"

  match 'tagged' => 'factoids#tagged', :as => 'tagged'

  get 'tags/:tag', to: 'factoids#index', as: :tag

  root :to => 'home#index'

end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You dont need to go through all the trouble of creating a tag model and controller. `acts-as-taggable-on provides a method to find a list of all tags for the model.

```
2.0.0-p451 :008 > Factoid.tag_counts
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (2.0ms)  SELECT tags.*, taggings.tags_count AS count FROM "tags" JOIN (SELECT taggings.tag_id, COUNT(taggings.tag_id) AS tags_count FROM "taggings" INNER JOIN factoids ON factoids.id = taggings.taggable_id WHERE (taggings.taggable_type = 'Factoid' AND taggings.context = 'tags') AND (taggings.taggable_id IN(SELECT factoids.id FROM "factoids")) GROUP BY taggings.tag_id HAVING COUNT(taggings.tag_id) > 0) AS taggings ON taggings.tag_id = tags.id
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 1, name: "tag">]>
```

This will return a ActiveRecord::Relation of all the tag objects. You can run map on it to get a array of tags

```
Factoid.tag_counts.map(&:name)
 => ["tag"]
```

Comment: Well that saved me a TON of work. :-) Thanks a bunch!