# How to get *ALL* tags on an acts_as_taggable object regardless of its contexts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on, acts-as-taggable

First things first.

This is **NOT** a duplicate of [Get all tags on taggable object - no matter context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689149/get-all-tags-on-taggable-object-no-matter-context). I am looking for all tags on a specific model object. Not for all possible tags in my entire rails app.

This is **NOT** a duplicate of [Listing all tags for an acts_as_taggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297903/listing-all-tags-for-an-acts-as-taggable). I am looking for all tag on an object on all contexts - not on just a single context.

---

I have a `my_car` instance of a `Car` class. I have many taggings on it on `wheel` context, on `body` context, on `interior` context, and some general tags on `tags` context.

While i am able to `my_car.tags_list`, `my_car.wheel_list`, `my_car.body_list`, `my_car.interior_list`, i am not able to do something like `my_car.all_tags` so that i can see **ALL** the tags on the `my_car` object regardless of their tagging contexts.

---

How do i do that?

Comment: Did you try `all_tags_list`?

Comment: `all_tags_list ` finds ONLY the ones that has the 'tags' context. Not all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`c.base_tags.map(&:name)`

There is no built-in shortcut to get the names directly, but that's short enough :)

Edit: `base_tags` is an association defined on classes declared as taggable: `has_many :base_tags, through: :taggings, source: :tag, class_name: '::ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag'`

Source: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable.rb

Comment: Perfect. This is nice. Thanks :)

Comment: can you help me understand where this `base_tags` method is defined? What is its source?

Comment: Thanks so much :)